# Unable to find linux-headers-2.6.32-amd64 for installing VirtualBox

Tags: linux, virtualbox, debian

I tried to install virtualBox on my Debian Server, but each time I try to start a virtual machine it tells me to do /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup.
Whenever I try to use this command it tells me this:

```
Stopping VirtualBox kernel modules ...done.
Uninstalling old VirtualBox DKMS kernel modules ...done.
Trying to register the VirtualBox kernel modules using DKMSError! Your kernel headers for kernel 2.6.32-amd64 cannot be found.
Please install the linux-headers-2.6.32-amd64 package,
or use the --kernelsourcedir option to tell DKMS where it's located
 ...failed!
  (Failed, trying without DKMS)
Recompiling VirtualBox kernel modules ...failed!
  (Look at /var/log/vbox-install.log to find out what went wrong)
```

When I try to install the package, it says it could not find it.

```
apt-get install linux-headers-2.6.32-amd64
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-headers-2.6.32-amd64
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-headers-2.6.32-amd64'
```

Where do I get that package?

Comment: Post output of `uname -a`

Comment: Linux x.rootpro.de 2.6.32-amd64 #1 SMP Tue Jul 8 10:43:10 MSK 2014 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Does `apt-cache search '.*headers-2\.6\.32.*'` give something useful?

Comment: I get an empty result.

Comment: I assume you did your `apt-get update` ?

Comment: How did you install your kernel?  What does `apt-cache policy linux-image-2.6.32` display?  (See if you can prune it down to just the essentials, i.e. the package and version you actually have installed -- maybe `apt-cache policy $(readlink /vmlinuz | sed 's%boot/vmlinux%linux-image%')`.)

Comment: I did not install the kernel by myself, it was installed by my server hoster. N: Unable to locate package linux-image-2.6.32
N: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-image-2.6.32' N: Unable to locate package boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-4-rt-amd64
N: Couldn't find any package by regex 'boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-4-rt-amd64'

Comment: And yes, I did apt-get update.

Comment: The error message indicates that you are running kernel 3.2.0-4-rt-amd64, not 2.6.32.  Can you obtain headers for that, and maybe coerce VirtualBox to use those headers?

Comment: Sorry, typo in my command, that should be `s%boot/vmlinuz%linux-image%`

Comment: apt-cache policy $(readlink /vmlinuz | sed 's%boot/vmlinuz%linux-image%')
linux-image-3.2.0-4-rt-amd64:
  Installed: 3.2.63-2
  Candidate: 3.2.63-2
  Version table:
 *** 3.2.63-2 0
        500 http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ wheezy/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     3.2.60-1+deb7u3 0
        500 http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates/main amd64 Packages

Comment: I installed it, but it is not in use, my hoster told me I can not switch to another kernel because of their stuff they're running next to my server. I also tried using the 3.2.0 headers, but it did not work.

Comment: The kernel was built by your hoster apparently, given the `x.rootpro.de` in your `uname -a` output. Ask your hoster for the linux-headers- package corresponding to the installed kernel. They should have installed that together with the kernel.

Answer (score 1):

A nice tool is `module-assistant`. Run `apt-get install module-assistant` and the use it to install linux-headers and build-essential is:

```
m-a update
```

And then:

```
m-a prepare
```